# How to makes two stacked divs have the same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a card. The card has two stacked divs. The top part of the card has an image and the bottom part is just text. What do I do to make sure the top and bottom divs have the same height? I know i could define heights of the divs in pixels, but I don't want to do that because I don't know much text will be on the other cards.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.cardTop, .cardBottom {
  border: 1px solid;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="cardTop">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="cardBottom">
    <p>text of the card goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.card div {height: 50px}`

Comment: set the same height to elements with different ancestors can't be done in css only. Or use images with the same size.

Comment: Use css flex box or javascript to handle heights

Comment: Unless the card has a known or ascertainable height, flexbox can't do this.

Comment: also... **what other cards**?

Comment: @Paulie_D this will be used for a custom WordPress theme, so i'm not sure how much text will be added in the future.

Answer (score -2):

Just use the styling of the flex-box like this :

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;

  padding: 5px;
  height: 15em; //chose what you want
  width: 15em;  //chose what you want
}

.card > div {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Your 2 divs will split at 50% height of your global .card container height by doing this.

I made a quick example online : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pechib

Comment: I think the point here is that the `card` height **is not known**.

Comment: You can use grid on card class, set the grid- template-row to 50% 50% and then card Top will have grid- row: 1; and cardBottom will have grid- row: 2;